# manifest for *** not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: jhipster, java-11, jhipster-registry, jhipster-gateway

I run docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up jhipster command, but I get this error =>
manifest for *** not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Comment: Have you built your image first? See https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#3

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by Gael Marziou,I think you might have to build your image first.

---

Sample example:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/